# Discord Bot Delay after giving 1 command

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    earnings = random.randrange(269)

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Got {earnings} Coins!!')

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

I am making an Economy bot for my discord server in which I have added a work command that'll give
user some random amount of money after typing `$work` , but I want that people won't spam that command to earn easy money , I want my bot to send a message like 'Take a break , try again after 15 sec' and only after 15 seconds , user will be able to use that command again

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable for the delay, and also a global dictionary declared in this scope.
Like this:

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(send_messages=True)
async def work(ctx):
    worker = ctx.message.author.nick # I use nick so that you can store the data in a .json file
    # You can also use user.id
    if worker in delays.keys():
        if delays[worker] == 0:
            # Work
            delays[worker] = 15 # Seconds
            for i in reversed(range(delays[worker])):
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                delays[worker] = i
            delays[worker] = 0
    else:
        # Let this poor man work
        delays[worker] = 0
```

---

Then, I suggest to store the datas into the `.json` file only when the bot is stopped.
Otherwise it will take lot of time for each time to open the file, store the datas, and then close it.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works and you don't need any more help, you can accept the answer. Hope it will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

##### While FLAK-ZOSO's answer works, there's a better way to do it

In fact, discord.py (or Nextcord) has *builtin* support for it (btw in order to use `commands.anything`, you have to do `from [discord/nextcord].ext import commands` at the top):

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown([cooldown in seconds], [how many times you can run the command before hitting the cooldown], type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    earnings = random.randrange(269)

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Got {earnings} Coins!!')

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

Also, if you want a channel specific, server specific, role specific, etc. cooldown instead of a user specific one, change the BucketType to one of the following options:

- `commands.BucketType.default` for a global cooldown (across servers)
- `commands.BucketType.guild` for a server specific cooldown
- `commands.BucketType.channel` for a channel specific cooldown
- `commands.BucketType.member` for a member specific cooldown (this is different than `commands.BucketType.user` because per user is global, so even if the user moves to a different server they'll still have the same cooldown whereas `BucketType.member` is server-specific, so if the user switches servers and runs the command again, there will be 2 seperate cooldowns)
- `commands.BucketType.category` for a category specific cooldown
- `commands.BucketType.role` for a role specific cooldown

Comment: ```@commands.cooldown(15, 1, type=commands.BucketType.role(886523934898528307))```     bro it is showing ```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'channel'``` for a role specific cooldown

Comment: and I also want it to show specific message after hitting the cooldown like ' please wait for 15 sec'